# Resample jpeg in svg <image> tag after scaling the svg container

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, css-transforms

Is there any way to resample a raster picture inside an `<image>` tag that itself is inside a `<svg>` container after I scale (transform) the container?
I have a 640x640px jpeg. It looks like this on the page (it's a popup on a map that enlarges on hover).

```
<svg class="photo" style="top: 425px; left: 1406px;">
    <image width="64" height="64" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="../images/someimg.jpg"></image>
</svg>
```

css:

```
.photo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    transform-origin: 50% 119%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #999;
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.photo image {
    clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

clipped by

```
<svg>
    <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper">
        <polygon points="0,0 56,0 56,56 36,56 28,64 20,56 0,56 0,0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Previously I tried css scaling:

```
 photo:hover {
     transform: scale(2.5);
 }
```

it worked great: the `<image>` inside looked sharp after the transform, but hover itself looked ugly when interrupted. So I tried to do it with `d3.transition()`

```
$photoSvg.on('mouseover', function() {
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(400)
            .style('transform', 'scale(2.5)');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(400)
            .style('transform', 'scale(1)');
    });
```

There is a strange effect now. When I first hover after the page reload there is no transition but the svg scales and the `<image>` looks kind of sharp. But on consecutive transitions I see the animation but the image is sharp only when it is small. When it is scaled 2.5 times it looks just like a stretched image from scale(1).
Any light shed would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you could take the source image, draw it on a scaled down canvas, generate an base64 encoding of that image from the canvas and put it back in the image. quite laborious. :)

Comment: @toskv thanks for suggestion, indeed sounds like sending man on Mars. So far I resolved it by scaling the `<image>` itself with `overflow: visible` on svg container